# How can I install some nix packages?

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

I know how to install some `nix` packages with `nix-env` but there are some of them I have no clue how to install,

for example:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/python-modules/pygit2/default.nix

How to install that package?

How can I know the full name of the package just looking at the `.nix` file?**

Answer (score 1):

> How to install that package?

`nix-env -iA nixos.python3Packages.pygit2`. You can replace `python3Packages` with your python version of choice, e.g. `python36Packages` instead.

> How can I know the full name of the package just looking at the .nix file?

You just cannot.
The reason is that the attribute path of the .nix file is determined by how it is referenced from `<nixpkgs>/pkgs/all-packages/top-level.nix`. In this case, the top-level.nix file makes all python packages accessible through the `pythonPackages` or `python3packages` attribute. The packages themselves are listed in `<nixpkgs>/pkgs/all-packages/python-packages.nix` where each entry now finally calls the nix expression file of the package, like the one you linked to above.

This makes the full attribute path of the package `pkgs.python3Packages.pygit2`. A great tool to browse around the nixkpgs attribute set is `nix repl "<nixpkgs/nixos>"`, which drops you into a nix interpreter with tab-completion.
When using `nix-env` for imperative software installation, you still have to substite `pkgs` by `nixos` in the package's attribute path.
I recommend you looking into *declarative software management* instead anyways, as there you can use the normal attribute path of the package.